# IME in Android Studio emulator not responding to Shift-B on keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, ime

I noticed that Shift-B is not being recorded or received on EditTexts when I am using the emulator with my physical keyboard.

- Keyboard works fine elsewhere in all other programs - "B" - see!
- Lower-case ''b' works fine everywhere
- All other SHIFT alphabet characters work from the keyboard except "B"
- Clicking on shift-B on the IME (soft keyboard) works fine
- When pressing SHIFT-b, the `onKeyListener.onKey()` receives a keyCode of 0

I have used Android Studio and the Emulator extensively for a year and just now noticed this. I am not sure when it began.

I have quit and restarted Android Studio and the Emulator to no avail.

I am guessing that I somehow have a key map messed up by accident or corruption, but I do not know where to begin fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the emulator and was fixed in 27.0.5 that was released in the past week.

Comment: I have the latest Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022
The bug is still (or again) present on my machine. Maybe it is a different bug: No capital letter appears (nothing) when pressing shift + letter.

Comment: @Jörg It's maybe because of camera app issue. go to camera app on emulator and press shift and go around app, then close camera app, probably problem has been solved.