# Android Studio Emulator Upper Case B not typing

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation, keyboard-input

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and building applications for SDK with following settings:

```
    flavorDimensions "default"
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.logi3pl.wms.wmsmobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.23"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
```

After a recent update, none of my AVD emulators are accepting uppercase 'B' from keyboard. Lower case 'b' and all other chars are working upper/lower case. On-screen keyboard accepts uppercase 'B'.

Not only the software I am coding, but also google search bar and every other app on the device has the same problem.

Don't know even where to look at. Appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the time to change your keyboard bro.

Comment: It's a laptop. External keyboards not working too.

Comment: So it's time to change your laptop bro ;)

Comment: That's a very 'uncertain' suggestion, no wonder why :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, using Android Studio 3.01, Android 7.1.1 (emulated Pixel API 25).

I filed a report to Google.

**Update:**
They fixed it in Version 27.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the newest update. The problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045540/ime-in-android-studio-emulator-not-responding-to-shift-b-on-keyboard   but it was also fixed for me by 27.0.5